# Use svelte css class in @html

Tags: svelte

I have an api that returns html with classes, I want to know how I can use svelte style definition for those.

App.Svelte

```
<script>
    let string = `<span class="status">ok</span>`;
</script>

<p>{@html string}</p>

<style>
    .status {
        color: red
    }
</style>
... 

{@html marked}
```

Returns
`Unused CSS selector (8:1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Svelte will remove all CSS it cannot find in the markup, which is why it's removing the `status` class in your sample.  There is however a way to tell Svelte to leave these classes alone and that's by simply declaring them *global*:

`:global(.status) { }`

Beware that this would apply these styles to **ALL** *.status* classes in your app, to still have some scoping you could make this a child selector somehow

```html
<style>
 .wrapper > :global(.status) {
 }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
  {@html marked}
</div>
```

This way it will only be applied to *status* classes inside of *wrapper*.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this with the h2 tag, since I am integrating tincyMCE in a svelte app that is using 'flowbite-svelte'.  What worked for me was:

```
    :global(.content h2) {
        font-size: 1.5em;
      }
```

Where 'content' was my div class.